# Condizionale o congiuntivo presente dopo il condizionale?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, grammar

So che il titolo potrebbe risultare fuorviante, ma cercherò di fare degli esempi:

1.Potrebbe essere possibile che sia cosi.

2.Potrebbe essere possibile che sarebbe così.

3.Potrebbe darsi che sia così.

4.Potrebbe darsi che sarebbe così.

Nella prima frase abbiamo un congiuntivo presente posto dopo il condizionale, il che infrangerebbe la regola che dopo il condizionale ci vuole l'imperfetto congiuntivo (es:vorrei che fossi).

Nella seconda e la quarta abbiamo un condizionale seguito da un altro condizionale.

Credo che però che nel caso della seconda e la quarta ciò sia possibile perché il condizionale nella subordinata esplicita ("che sarebbe così") ha un periodo ipotetico **nascosto**, ovvero:

"Potrebbe darsi che, **se succedesse questo**, sarebbe così".

"Potrebbe essere possibile che magari sarebbe così **qualora si verificasse questo**".

"Questo potrebbe essere possibile, ovvero che sarebbe così **qualora ci fossero questi presupposti**".

Questa è la mia chiave di lettura per la seconda e quarta frase, mentre per la prima e la terza sono quasi sicuro che la scelta corretta sia il congiuntivo imperfetto e non il congiuntivo presente, o quantomeno sarebbe una delle due opzioni corrette.

Siete d'accordo con la mia analisi sulla seconda e quarta frase?
Cosa mi dite invece della prima e terza? È davvero giusto usare l'imperfetto congiuntivo dopo il condizionale presente, parlando di fatti che si svolgono in contemporanea nel presente, o si usa solo con specifici verbi( "vorrei che", "mi piacerebbe che" ecc...) e in casi di questo tipo?

Comment: “la regola che dopo il condizionale ci vuole l'imperfetto congiuntivo” Non c'è alcuna regola del genere: dipende dal tipo di verbo della reggente, dal suo tempo, dalla contemporaneità o meno tra reggente e secondaria. Su questo e sul resto della domanda, consiglio _Italiano_ di Serianni, la parte sulla sintassi del periodo, e in particolare XIV.55-8.

Comment: Cercherei comunque qualcosa di meglio di “potrebbe essere possibile che sia così”; in italiano si direbbe “potrebbe essere così”.

Answer (score -2):

I condizionali, in questo particolare caso, stanno esprimendo un ipotesi e quindi va appunto seguito da un congiuntivo. La forma mentis o logica e' molto vicina alle ipotesi della realta' e irrealta' dell'Inglese. (per capirla in maniera semplice).

L'unico dubbio che mi viene in mente leggendo le diverse frasi e' che il verbo potrebbe debba andare coniugato con il "puo'". A livello parlato e grammaticalmente suona meglio.

> 1.Potrebbe essere possibile che sia cosi.

PUO'/POTREBBE ESSERRE POSSIBILE (CHE) SIA COSI

> 2.Potrebbe essere possibile che sarebbe così.

Sarebbe non e' corretto

> 3. Potrebbe darsi che sia così.

Nel parlato italiano standard (inguisticamente parlando) suona meglio dire: Puo' darsi sia cosi.

> 4.Potrebbe darsi che sarebbe così.*

Incorretto.

Il che in italiano e' linguisticamente detto 'che polivalente'

Spero sia di aiuto nella ricerca della corretta risposta

Saluti