# "Dobbiamo" o "dovremmo" dopo "credo che"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, moods

Which of the translation below is the best for the following sentence?

> I think that we should accept the fact that [...]

> *Credo che **dobbiamo** accettare il fatto che [...]*
> *Credo che **dovremmo** accettare il fatto che [...]*

Also, is the first one correct at all from the perspective of tenses?

Comment: Duplicate: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/condizionale-o-congiuntivo-presente-dopo-il-condizionale ?

Comment: @DaG I'm not sure it is a duplicate; the question you mention is about something different with *potere* instead of *credere*.

Answer (score 1):

In Italian this is a *proposizione subordinata completiva oggettiva esplicita*.

- *completiva* because the main clause (*`*`Credo.*) would be meaningless on its own, in this context.
- *oggettiva* because it substitutes a *complemento oggetto*: *penso **questa cosa***.
- *esplicita* because it's introduced by *che* (not by *di*).

As mentioned in [Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-oggettive_(La-grammatica-italiana)), the verb mood can be *indicativo*, *congiuntivo* or *condizionale*. So both your translations are grammatically sound.

The second version, with *dovremmo*, uses *condizionale* and so it indicates a less strong belief, so I think this is a better translation.

In the first version *dobbiamo* is likely *congiuntivo* (it could also technically be *indicativo*) - I think this would better translate as "I think we **have to** accept that [...]".